# Create an installation ISO image from and of an existing Ubuntu Linux installation on a USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, bootable, clone

Trying to find out the best and possibly easier way to create an installation ISO image from and of an existing Ubuntu Linux installation. I can then use a LiLi like tool to then make it bootable on a USB drive. But need to create an ISO like this one, which then boot up will prompt to install it on the machine I am installing it on. Safe to assume the machine I need to create ISO from and the machine I will install ISO to are the same HW wise, just that the other machine does not have internet.

Comment: Do you want an "installation" or a "live" image? In general you will not be able to make an installation image because the running system will not have the installer on it. You could take an Ubuntu installation image and add additional packages based on the output of `dpkg -l` to get you an installer that can get you to the same unconfigured state.

Comment: Oh, that would help too. Infact, I would prefer that. Can you please help point out a way to create an installer of all packages on my system, so that once I install the same Ubuntu ISO on another machine, all I need to do is install the package to replicate the systems.

Comment: The straight forward thing to do would be to do this in 2 steps. Step 1 would be to get the installer ISO image from ubuntu, and use that to install a base image. The second step would be to duplicate the packages. You can get a list of packages by `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ { print $2}' > packages_I_have` and then on the new machine run `apt-get update ; apt-get install -y $(cat packages_I_have)` after you have copied the packages_I_have file from one machine to the other.

Comment: There is also `dpkg --get-selections` and `dpkg --setselections` to transfer the list of desired packages.

Comment: Oh, but the problem is, the other machine does not have internet. That was the initial need of having to replicate the machines by first installing ISO on the machine which has internet, install all packages, create an ISO and then install the same OS on the machine with no internet.

Comment: In that case you can use the `apt-get install -d $(cat packages_I_have)` on the machine with the internet access to download all the packages, copy the `/var/cache/apt` tree onto your usb and off again on the target machine.

Comment: So, **Machine#1**, first `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ { print $2}' > packages_I_have`, second `apt-get install -d $(cat packages_I_have)`, third `sudo cp -r /var/cache/apt /media/username/usb_drive` and then on the machine with no internet, **Machine#2**, first `cp /media/username/usb_drive /var/cache/apt`, second `apt-get update; apt-get install -y $(cat packages_I_have)`